# Calculate bandwidth of the WiFi or WiFi signal strength

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want to calculate bandwidth of the WiFi or WiFi signal strength using jQuery or  JavaScript. I know we can calculate strength on server side code, but I want to calculate on client side.

Comment: You cannot calculate neither WIFI bandwidth nor signal strength using javascript, because you have no access to low-level functions required to this. You can, hoewver, test the bandwidth between the client and the server. Is that what you actually want?

Answer (score 2):

Check this website, I think this will suit for WiFi connection:

> http://www.wiseloop.com/demo/javascript-bandwidth-tester

Here is an example of a calculating download speed when loading an image:

```js
var imageAddr = "http://www.tranquilmusic.ca/images/cats/Cat2.JPG" + "?n=" + Math.random();
var startTime, endTime;
var downloadSize = 5616998;
var download = new Image();

download.onload = function() {
  endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  showResults();
}

startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
download.src = imageAddr;

function showResults() {
  var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000; //Math.round()
  var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
  var speedBps = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
  var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
  var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
  alert("Your connection speed is: \n" +
    speedBps + " bps\n" +
    speedKbps + " kbps\n" +
    speedMbps + " Mbps\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you praveen its helpfull for me.

Comment: You should put more code from the fiddle into you answer. As you've not mentioned that you can actually calculate it by timing how long it takes to download an image. You've just shown a function that shows the results.

Comment: @MattJHoughton I integrated the JSFiddle code directly into a snippet. No need to navigate to an external site to run this code.