# How to find signal strength of Wi-Fi connection in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am building a WP8.1 app & I need to know whether it is possible to find the signal strength of the available Wi-Fi connections programmatically? Searched a lot & at last reached here. Any suggestions/samples would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: check this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213644/how-calculate-bandwidth-of-the-wifi-or-wifi-signal-strength-using-jquery-or-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a general level from the ConnectionProfile's GetSignalBars() method:

```
IReadOnlyList<ConnectionProfile> profiles = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
foreach (ConnectionProfile profile in profiles)
{
    if (profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() != NetworkConnectivityLevel.None)
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} bars", profile.ProfileName, profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel(), profile.GetSignalBars());
}
```

Windows Phone doesn't provide more detailed information about the signal strength.